# How to Put 4 images aside each other with text beneath each of them?

Tags: css, html

I want to accomplish this with only HTML and CSS

[image: 4 images aside with text beneath each of them]

Another example from bbc.com

[image: another example from bbc]

I want them to be separated from each other.

this is the code I made so far

```css
        .newsitems {
        display : inline-block;

        }
```

```html
<div class="newsitems">
<img src="download.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0">
<h2>heading here</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum diam est, ornare in lorem et, dignissim pharetra eros.</span>
</div>

<div class="newsitems">
<img src="download.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0">
<h2>heading here</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum diam est, ornare in lorem et, dignissim pharetra eros.</span>
</div>

<div class="newsitems">
<img src="download.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0">
<h2>heading here</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum diam est, ornare in lorem et, dignissim pharetra eros.</span>
</div>

<div class="newsitems">
<img src="download.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0">
<h2>heading here</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum diam est, ornare in lorem et, dignissim pharetra eros.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: post details or code on what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to make it easly and keep it responsive:

```css
main{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}

.newsitems{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="newsitems">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0">
<h2>heading here</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum diam est, ornare in lorem et, dignissim pharetra eros.</span>
</div>

<div class="newsitems">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0">
<h2>heading here</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum diam est, ornare in lorem et, dignissim pharetra eros.</span>
</div>

<div class="newsitems">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0">
<h2>heading here</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum diam est, ornare in lorem et, dignissim pharetra eros.</span>
</div>

<div class="newsitems">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0">
<h2>heading here</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum diam est, ornare in lorem et, dignissim pharetra eros.</span>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: unfortunately not working very well. the text is on the image. and if there is no text the images will be placed over each other.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code? This way it would be easier to help

Comment: kindly check my post now

Comment: @MostafaNafady I have modified your fiddle, I wrapped all the elements into a `main` container and I have given your `.newsitems` class a fixed width. https://jsfiddle.net/d1qb26td/21/

Comment: it works now very well, exactly as I wanted, kindly edit your answer with this fiddle you made so I could choose it a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't post code now, but it's simple 
Just display all divs as block 
Add the image inside the div, then 
Write the text inside the div as well 
Then in CSS just add something like this : 
.divname{
position:absolute;

}
Then set the proper value(px) of right/left, top/bottom positions , and set a width and height

Answer (score 0):

```
you have two options either you use flex or you can also use the bootstrap class to acheive this (which is basically made up of flex)
1 : Bootstrap code

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> div1 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> div1 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> div1 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> div1 </div>
</div>


2: use pure css/ SCSS (using flex)


<div class="main-container">
  <div class="item-container">
        <img src=""/>
        <div> Text area </div>
   </div>
     <div class="item-container">
        <img src=""/>
        <div> Text area </div>
   </div>
    <div class="item-container">
        <img src=""/>
        <div> Text area </div>
   </div>
    <div class="item-container">
        <img src=""/>
        <div> Text area </div>
   </div>

</div>


SCSS

.main-container{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
width:100%;
align-items:center;
flex-flow:row wrap;
}

.item-container
{
   display:flex;
  width:20%;
flex-flow:column nowrap;
img
{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;

}
div
{
 font-size:12px;
}

}
```